# moodle form api add more

Tags: php, moodle

)

ok here is my problem :

im trying to create form with form API 
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_Form_Definition

so far so good but i have no option to duplicate custom form.

```
$mform->addElement('header', 'newmodulefieldset', 'add time with audio and text here');
$mform->addElement('html','<div class="panel panel-default">');
$mform->addElement('text', 'time',  'time', array('size' => '64'));
$mform->addElement('text', 'audio',  'audio', array('size' => '64'));
//$mform->addElement('filepicker', 'userfile', 'audio', null, array( 'accepted_types' => '*'));
$mform->addElement('text', 'entxt',  'en text', array('size' => '64'));
$mform->addElement('text', 'fatxt',  'fa text', array('size' => '64'));
$mform->addElement('html','</div>');
$mform->addElement('button', 'another','add another one');
```

this is my code, i need assign action to button to re create all this elements.

how can i do this ?

Comment: The only way you can do is using javascript to duplicate all elements

Answer (score 2):

This function adds a repeating group of elements. An array index starting with a zero index will be added to the elementname so that the form will return arrays of submitted values.

**Also on the form there will be a button to add extra elements to the form. The form page reloads with extra form elements. This involves no javascript.** SO every time you request, page will be reload.

```
repeat_elements()
```

use case

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_repeat_elements